# Loading Ubuntu on new SSD

Tags: boot, system-installation, ssd

I'm about at the end of my rope.  After several attempts to get a good download of 14.04.1 LTE, I'm now getting incredibly frustrated on the install.

I can boot from DVD/USB just fine, but when I attempt an install, I get a file error message:

The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk:

```
[Errno5] Input/Output error
```

It doesn't matter if it's from DVD or USB, or from USB boot desktop or from the initial boot options, I get the same error message.  I do not check the "download updates while installing" or "install 3rd party software" boxes. I do not encrypt the installation or use LVM.  File check of both the DVD and USB (from the install option screen) are clean.  The only thing I can think of being the culprit is the SSD.

The SSD in question is an Axiom Signature III 240 GB drive on 0.  Gigabyte motherboard with an i7-4770k 3.50Ghz x 8 16G RAM.

Comment: I/O errors generally mean there is something wrong with the hard disk.

Comment: Is this a new SSD disk?  Have you ever run fstrim on it?

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates you likely have a hardware problem with your system.

This problem could be with the drive itself (it is not unheard of for even a brand new drive to have a fault), or with something else such as your computer's motherboard.

Troubleshooting steps which could help narrow it down include trying the same on a different drive (removing the problem drive from your system). You could even try installing onto a USB drive to see if it's a problem even when not using your SATA interface.

You could try partitioning and formatting the drive from a live CD and see if there are any problems.